# How to preserve mat-table row state while updating datasource?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

I have a mat-table with expandable rows. When the datasource is updated, all the rows that are open are closed automatically and the page loses the scroll position.

How would i make the table data update while keeping the mat-table component from re-initialising and losing it's state?

example code:
[mat-table with expanded rows stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows?file=app%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html)

Answer (score 3):

I was just experimenting with the mat table api and the DataSource interface so maybe I am missing something but an option for what you describe is to avoid creating a new observable each time mat table internally calls the connect method. Instead, return a `BehaviorSubject` and call `next` whenever new data are available.

Based on your stackblitz example, just modifying the ExampleDataSource by returning a BehaviorSubject and adding a new method, to use whenever new data should be available to the table:

```
export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  private _data$: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  data$ = this._data$.asObservable();

  update(data) {
    const rows = [];
    data.forEach(element => rows.push(element, { detailRow: true, element }));
    this._data$.next(rows);
  }
  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<Element[]> {
    return this.data$;
  }

  disconnect() { }
}
```

And the [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows-wunz8k?file=app%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts), I am triggering data update with reverse order in a timeout to verify.